# How to execute system commands?

Tags: clojure

How can I execute system specific commands and get their response in Clojure? For example, let's assume we're on a Linux machine, how can I call `top` or `free`, and get their results for further processing?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
(use '[clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])
(sh "free")
(sh "top" "-bn1")
```

See also: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.java.shell/sh

Comment: Thanks for the example and link. `clojure.java.shell/sh` works well on Linux machines, but not on Windows machines; is there a different shell for Windows?

Comment: I don't see any problem with Windows, (sh "calc") works normally on my system. As does (sh "notepad" "C:/windows/WindowsUpdate.log") . Whats the problem with this solution on your system ?

Comment: @NielsK: I had trouble calling the cmd prompt and passing it a command, i.e. `sh "cmd" "dir"`

Comment: @sjac: To get the command processor to execute a command for you, you need to use the `/C` option, i.e. (untested): `sh "cmd" "/C" "dir"`. This is explained by (in the DOS window) `help cmd`.

Comment: What about easier way to show the output similar to that of native bash commands

Comment: @PrayagUpd That sounds like a different question. You should ask it separately, and with more detail.

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to use the Java Runtime.exec method as follows:

```
(import 'java.lang.Runtime)

(. (Runtime/getRuntime) exec "your-command-line-here")
```

The Runtime.exec method returns a [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object that you can query to get the standard output etc. as needed.

Comment: Dont forget to use array of string if command has arguments: `(. (Runtime/getRuntime) exec (into-array ["command" "arg1" "arg2"]))`

Comment: In the most recent alphas of clojure 1.12.0 there is a java process api
https://clojure.org/releases/devchangelog , CLJ-2759, in the namespace clojure.java.process https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/java/process.clj

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to get a little higher in term of abstractions (although no that high), I would recommend [Conch](https://github.com/Raynes/conch), as I found it to make very readable code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [babashka](https://github.com/babashka/babashka.) library to run shell commands in Clojure.  An example would be

```
#!/usr/bin/env bb
(require '[clojure.java.shell :refer [sh]])
(sh "top")
```