# Can anyone explain me about the sh in clojure in order to execute the system command?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec, clojure-core.logic

I'm using Mac OS. I want to execute a system command using `(use '[clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])`, like in [How to execute system commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734908/how-to-execute-system-commands). I have read https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.shell/sh but wasn't able to understand things like how many parameters can be passed in one syntax, etc.

In windows I have tried `(sh "cmd" "/C" "dir")`and it was working but in Mac OS, how do I execute the above syntax? Moreover I want to pass more parameters than just `dir`. For example, I want to execute `(sh "cmd" "/c" "mged" "test.g")`.
NOTE: `mged` and `test.g` are referred from `Brl-Cad`.

I want to draw a sphere using above example.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS or Linux this works:

```
user=> (require '[clojure.java.shell :as sh])
nil
user=> (sh/sh "ls" "-la")
...
```

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you after so many days and thank you for the explanation. This is the code I'm using ```(ns vikram-cad.core (:require [clojure.java.shell :refer [sh]])) (defn example [] (println (:out (sh "mged" "test.g"))))``` So can you help me with creating a database of any name ex ``test.g`` and a sphere with sh function in clojure

Comment: Upon executing the above codes I'm getting this error ``Execution error (IOException) at java.lang.ProcessImpl/forkAndExec (ProcessImpl.java:-2).
error=2, No such file or directory``

Answer (score 1):

`clojure.java.shell` just spawns the process with the given arguments (and `:env` and `:dir` and ... - see the doc).  So first of all there is most likely no `cmd` on OSX/Unix, but there usually is a shell.  And the "same" as `cmd /c` on the shell is `-c`.  `-c` takes *one* argument and you can write your "shell code" there - that means you can use pipes, redirects, env-vars, ... - so if you just want to execute a tool with a param, use:

```clj
(sh "mged" "test".g")
```

If you want "shell features" use:

```clj
(sh "/bin/sh" "-c" "echo ${TERM} | tr x u")
```

(note that the "shell code" is just one argument)

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you after so many days and thank you @cfrick for the explanation. So now I can use sh function in clojure program and now it is working also, but this ``(sh "mged" "test.g)`` is not working means it is not creating any database of name ``test.g``. This is the code I'm using 
```(ns vikram-cad.core
(:require [clojure.java.shell :refer [sh]]))

(defn example []
(println (:out (sh "mged" "test.g"))))```
So can you help me with creating a database and a sphere with sh function in clojure

Comment: If you have errors or further insight in your problem, edit your question. Most likely something usefull is in the result of `sh` - so don't just look at `:out`.

Comment: Upon executing above code I'm getting this error ``Execution error (IOException) at java.lang.ProcessImpl/forkAndExec (ProcessImpl.java:-2).
error=2, No such file or directory``

Comment: Then most llikely `mged` is not in your path

Comment: But I already added the path. ``/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:Applications/BRL-CAD\ \:\ MGED\ 7.24.0.app/Contents/Resources/rel-7.24.0/bin:/opt/X11/bin``

Comment: Why don't you just use the absolute path to that binary then?

Comment: I tried that with absolute path also but getting same error.